# System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(), AssemblyResolve event and handling 3rd party dependencies

Tags: vb.net, autodesk, autodesk-inventor

I have this class which will hopefully let me essentially hot-load my .dll's, so that I can push changes to them while my coworkers are using them, without needing them to totally restart the application to begin seeing the effects.

I had been using `.LoadFrom()`, but found it preferred using already-loaded versions of the files, whereas `.LoadFile()` takes the latest. The catch being that any dependencies the loaded file needs have to be loaded as well. But I've managed to do this by listening to the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event, and it seems to work for any of the custom .dll's.

But we also have third-party dependencies (Autodesk Inventor 2022 .dll's) which my Visual Studio projects/solution don't generate automatically in my build folder (despite a couple I *have* had to include), and which I can't find anywhere on my machine. I've tried using `.Load()` for these, but it doesn't find anything (again, I guess, because they don't seem to be actually on my machine; the first one I consistently encounter is "Autodesk.iLogic.Core.resources.dll").

A 'FileNotFoundException' (not the one in the class) is thrown when the script instantiating the class runs within Inventor, so maybe my `AppDomain`(?) is the same as Inventor's, and by using `.LoadFile()` I'm obligated to resolve Inventor's dependencies too, but I really have no idea.

If this is some kind of problem that can't be fixed, are there any other strategies that might work to let me work as though the .dll's aren't locked, while remaining agnostic to the version number?

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection

Public NotInheritable Class LibInterface
    Private Const sBuildDir As String = "F:\Lib\Build"
    Private Const sReleaseRootDir As String = "F:\Lib\Releases"

    Private _oAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = Nothing
    Public Property oAssembly() As System.Reflection.Assembly
        Get
            Return _oAssembly
        End Get
        Protected Set(oVal As System.Reflection.Assembly)
            _oAssembly = oVal
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _oType As Type = Nothing
    Public Property oType() As Type
        Get
            Return _oType
        End Get
        Protected Set(oVal As Type)
            _oType = oVal
        End Set
    End Property


    Private Class Initialiser
        Public Sub New(
            ByVal oParent As LibInterface
        )
            AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf oParent.HandleResolve
        End Sub
    End Class

    Private _initialiser As New Initialiser(Me)

    Public Function HandleResolve(
        ByVal sender As Object _
        , ByVal args As ResolveEventArgs
    ) As System.Reflection.Assembly
        Return _GetAssembly(Split(args.Name, ",")(0)) + ".dll")
    End Function


    Private Function _GetAssembly(
        ByVal sFileName As String
    ) As System.Reflection.Assembly
        Return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(_SearchLastBuild(sFileName))
    End Function

    Private Function _SearchLastBuild(
        ByVal sFileName As String
    ) As String
        Dim sPathName = System.IO.Path.Combine(sBuildDir, sFileName)
        If Not File.Exists(sPathName) Then
            Throw New FileNotFoundException(".dll not found", sPathName)
        End If
        Dim oVersionInfo As FileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(sPathName)
        Dim sReleaseDir As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(sReleaseRootDir, oVersionInfo.FileVersion)
        Dim sReleasePathName = System.IO.Path.Combine(sReleaseDir, sFileName)
        If File.Exists(sReleasePathName) Then
            Return sReleasePathName
        End If
        Directory.CreateDirectory(sReleaseDir)
        _CopyFilesRecursively(sBuildDir, sReleaseDir)
        Return sReleasePathName
    End Function

    Private Sub _CopyFilesRecursively(
        ByVal sSrcPath As String _
        , ByVal sDestPath As String
    )
        For Each sDirPath As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sSrcPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(sDirPath.Replace(sSrcPath, sDestPath))
        Next
        For Each sOldPath As String In Directory.GetFiles(sSrcPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            File.Copy(sOldPath, sOldPath.Replace(sSrcPath, sDestPath), True)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(
        ByVal sFileName As String _
        , ByVal sType As String
    )
        _oAssembly = _GetAssembly(sFileName)
        _oType = _oAssembly.GetType(sType, False)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any advice or guidance is much appreciated
Thanks!